# Reference a "line" in a two-dimensional array

Tags: vb.net, arrays

how do I reference (pass as a parameter) a "line" of the two-dimensional

```
Dim Values As Object(,)
```

I.e. I want to write a function that expects a one-dimensional array of `Object`, i.e. `Object()`, and pass for example `Values(1)` to pass the values `Values (1,lowerbound)` through `Values (1,upperbound)` to my function as a one-dimensional array.

How do I do that?

VB10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all. It is not possible in VB.

Comment: Could anybody acknowledge this worst-of-all-answer of mine? Pleeeeze....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977933/how-to-get-sub-array-from-larger-array-in-vb-net makes me believe that I cannot reference the "line", I would have to COPY all elements contained in the "line" into a new array.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the truth. Too bad.