# VBA: N-Dimensional Array Library

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array, sub-array

**Is there an alternative method to access an array in VBA?**

I was creating a N-Dimensional Array Library when I realized that it is impossible to implement such a library of helpers without an alternative method to access an array in VBA...

For example using an array as an index?:

```
' instead of foo(6,2)=source(1,3,6,2) :
Dim idx1, idx2
idx1 = Array(6,2): idx2 = Array(1,3,6,2)
foo(idx1) = source(idx2)
```

The idea is to create/copy/change/merge ***SubArrays***. For example:

```
Dim blnPending as Boolean
Dim idx1, idx2

idx1 = Array(0,0): idx2 = Array(1,3,0,0)
blnPending = True
Do While blnPending
    foo(idx1) = source(idx2)
    blnPending = IndexIncrease (idx1, PivotDimension:= -1)
    IndexIncrease idx2, PivotDimension:= 1 ' second param just to reflect the idea of usage
Loop
```

**Same problem with Redim in this particular**

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps something that can only be made using an Add-In made by VB.NET? (ExcelDNA): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977933/how-to-get-sub-array-from-larger-array-in-vb-net

Comment: I can't see exactly what you're trying to do in your example, but to answer the title question, you can access the SafeArray structure in VBA, using the `VarPtrArray` API and the `RtlMoveMemory` API. It's a real hair-puller, though, as Excel crashes on pretty much any bug in your code, so developing takes forever and a day.

Comment: Re my previous comment, I used this site quite a bit when learning about pointers in VBA: http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-getting-pointers/ and it does cover arrays.